# Get default value for start and end in SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, swiperefreshlayout

[SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) has a method called `setProgressViewOffset` where you can set start and end parameter:

> start:    The offset in pixels from the top of this view at which the
>   progress spinner should appear.
>
> end:    The offset in pixels from the top of this view at which the progress spinner should come to rest after a successful swipe gesture.

It is useful when we have a floating actionBar/Toolbar, and have added a header to our ListView and want to start the SwipeRefresh from bottom of header View.

I wonder how can I get the default start and end value?

Then for instance for end parameter, I can pass default end + actionBarSize to the setProgressViewOffset.

Comment: can't you just pass headerHeight + actionbar height as end parameter ?

Comment: headerHeight have the same size as actionbar height. It is a Framelayout with ListView and Toolbar on top of that. So header will cover the space under Toolbar. Of course I can pass what you suggest but that is not the answer to this question.

Comment: I am using the same thing, and it is working without overlapping the two bars (actionbar + headerview)

Comment: good to know and what do you pass as start?

Comment: 0 or -actionbar height (probably 0 tough),  but it shouldn't really matter

Answer (score 0):

try this values .. extracted from the SwipeRefreshLayout class

```
int DEFAULT_CIRCLE_TARGET = 64;
final DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
swipeLayout.setProgressViewOffset(true,swipeContainer.getProgressCircleDiameter(),(int)(DEFAULT_CIRCLE_TARGET *metrics.density));
```